# How long does Immigration and customs clearance take at Boston?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, south-african-citizens

I am immigrating to the US from South Africa and would like to know how long it takes to go thru customs and border patrol. My port of entry is Boston, with a  connecting flight to Minnesota.

My son is a US citizen, so does he go thru a different line at customs?